duplicate capture group
I've searched for this but can't get it to work so I will use a specific example.
Here is the string : [Ah 4d 6s]
I want to capture each card : Ah, 4d and 6s. The catch is there could be a variable number of cards present, 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5. The whole string may also not be present.
I can get it to work when the [] are not in the string. The spaces give me problems.
Here is what I've tried :
\[([\dJQKTAdsch]{2}){1,}\]?, 

but I get the "A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data" error.
Here are all the possibilities :
mddgfc: checks 
Tomi1981: folds 
DJPOPS613: folds [Ad] 
DJPOPS613: folds [Qh Qc] 
SchuDani: folds [2c As Ts] 
anshovel: folds [Ad 5d 4h 8h] 
pokerpummi: folds [2c 5h Ac 6d 7s]

I expect to parse out : <player name>: <action> <hole cards>

The <hole cards> may or may not be present and are enclosed in square 
brackets : [<card1> <card2> ...]

Here is the latest regex I tried :  

(.*?)\s?:\s?(\bfolds\b|\bchecks\b)(?:[|(?!^)\G\h+)*([\dJQKTAdsch]{2})*(?=[^][]*])*\s?$


What is your regex flavor/tool?

Extract with [a-zA-Z0-9]{2}.

I'm using https://regex101.com & java

You may use this regex to get all of your matches of 2 characters between [ and ]:
(?:
   ^
   ([^\s:]+)
   \h*:\h*
   (folds|checks)
   \h*
   (?:
      \[
      (?=[\dJQKTAdsch\h]*])
      |
      $
   )
   |
   \G(?!^)
   \h+
)
([\dJQKTAdsch]{2})?

PS: Note x (extended) mode in the demo.
RegEx Demo
RegEx Details:

(?:: Start 1st non-capture group

^: Start
^([^\s:]+): Match 1+ of any char that are not a : and whitespace in the 1st capture group
\h*:\h*: Match a : surrounded with optional spaces
(folds|checks): Match folds or checks in the 2nd capture group
\h*: Match 0 or more whitespaces
(?:: Start 2nd non-capture group

\[: Match a [
(?=[\dJQKTAdsch\h]*]): Lookahead to assert that we have a ] ahead after matching 0 or more of allowed characters
|: OR
$: End position


): End 2nd non-capture group
\G: Start right after end of the previous match
(?!^): Make sure we are not at the start
\h+: Match 1+ of whitespaces


): End non-capture group
([\dJQKTAdsch]{2})?: Optionally match 2 characters of given allowed character sets in 3rd capture group


Magic is due to use of \G which is a zero width anchor that asserts position at the end of the previous match.

There are times when the whole string brackets, [], and contents don't appear (within a larger string). I tried adding * after each group, but that didn't work.  any ideas.

Most of the time, the line I am parsing would be this : "hughdal: folds". I want to capture the player name plus the action "folds".
But sometime a player folds and shows his cards : "MDAISY57: folds [As Ah]". I want to capture his name, action and cards. He can show one card, two, up to all five.

it's actually fold or check. The cards are only displayed on a fold. Here is what I tried but it didn't quite work :
(.?)\s?:\s?(\bfolds\b|\bchecks\b)(?:[|(?!^)\G\h+)([\dJQKTAdsch]{2})(?=[^][]])*\s?$

Here are all possible strings for the regex :
"mddgfc: checks"
"Tomi1981: folds"
"DJPOPS613: folds [Ad]"
"DJPOPS613: folds [Qh Qc]"
"SchuDani: folds [2c As Ts]"
"anshovel: folds [Ad 5d 4h 8h]"
"pokerpummi: folds [2c 5h Ac 6d 7s]"
(Sorry I couldn't figure out how to make a list.)

I cannot read these values from comment. Click on edit link below your question and provide these examples. Also add your expected matches for each case.

Check my new demo with your examples

I was playing around with it and came up with something like this, it still has some empty matches due to the optional parts. https://regex101.com/r/6Ku2yD/1

Nice, this one is definitely better @Thefourthbird

It is just for fun, I will not post anything. You can use it or make it better as you are the master :-)

@Thefourthbird: Thanks. Feel free to post it as answer though I think OP wouldn't have realised this much complexity will be required :-)

RIght you are. It will take me a while to figure this out, but I appreciate everyone's input. Definately next level regex.

1st question : there is the 1st non capturing group - yet it captures things within it - I don't get that ? It implies you can capture things within a noncapturing group ?

@Thefourthbird: Please check: https://regex101.com/r/6Ku2yD/2 It avoids empty matches

@mgillett: Outer group is non capturing but there are 2 internal groups inside and those will capture text as desired.

@anubhava Brilliant ++

So you can have capturing groups inside non capturing groups ?

yes of course we can

That is counterintuitive to me. So the purpose of the outer non capturing group is for grouping the inner capturing groups ?
